# Woocoomerce only change single product page button css

Tags: css, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a **Add to Cart** button on **Single Product** page and I want to alter its looking. I do not want to change other buttons on my site.

```
.woocommerce #content input.button,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit,
.woocommerce a.button,
.woocommerce button.button,
.woocommerce input.button,
.woocommerce-page #content input.button,
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit,
.woocommerce-page a.button,
.woocommerce-page button.button,
.woocommerce-page input.button {
    background: #f2a700 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border: 2px solid #f2a700;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-top: -4px;
    width: 57%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `single-product` class included in the `<body>` tag of every WooCommerce **Single Product** page:

**CSS**

```
.single-product .single_add_to_cart_button {

    /* Style your button here */

}
```